# "gained privilege" banner shown at wrong level

Tags: support, privileges

I've just reached 30 reputation on my Stack Overflow account, and am now being shown a banner saying "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – vote up learn more"

That is great, except you get vote up rights at 15.

Comment: How long ago was it that you reached 15 reputation? i.e. what kind of time window are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

If we only showed you that you gained a privilege at the exact point you had that amount of reputation, many people would miss the notification.

For example:

- Some people may never have 15 reputation (they may get 11 and then be upvoted to 21).
- Some people may reach 15 rep and shortly after be upvoted to 25.

The system tracks when a rep threshold is reached and then notifies the user, **once**, of the new priv. The user then can dismiss the notification and it will **never** be shown again. Sometimes the rep levels match exactly, sometimes they are higher and very rarely they are lower.